# How to set option value of dropdown as selected

Tags: jquery

I'm using

```
var back_color = "#000000";
var id = 1;
var back_color = "#ffffff"
jQuery("#color"+id+" option[value=back_color]").attr("selected", "selected");
```

This is not working.

Comment: First thing to notice is that you're declaring the same variable twice...

Comment: `value=back_color` isn't accessing the variable `back_color` - if that's what you're trying to do. Also, you're declaring it twice.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the html markup for the `color1` element including its option elements. kojiro's answer should've solved the problem, but perhaps there is an issue in the code you haven't shown...

Answer (score 3):

```
var back_color = "#000000";
var id = 1;
// var back_color = "#ffffff" Why are you defining this twice?
```

Presumably you want the `back_color` value here, not just the literal word. (Also, not quoting the attribute value in an attribute selector is technically legal according to CSS, but in my experience jQuery will not work without the quotes.)

```
jQuery("#color"+id+" option[value='"+back_color+"']").attr("selected", "selected");
```

Comment: @Madu Help me help you. Describe in detail what you did, what you expected to happen and what *did* happen.

Comment: Actually, you can just do it like so : `$('#color1').val("#000000");​`

Comment: Or to make it dynamic: `$('#color'+id).val(back_color);` . Take a look at [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gRePK/)

Comment: @Jeemusu that's true, great point. Why don't you make it an answer?